# Function library with defined types

Tags: typescript

I am trying to compose functions in a way where I can define a name, input, and return types and then access them from a central function. However, when I do this I lose typing information.

How can I build a system like this without hard-coded value types?

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { promisify } from 'util';
import * as lodash from 'lodash';

const libs = []

export enum Types {
    number,
    numbers,
    string,
    buffer,
}

export enum Actions {
    add,
    subtract,
    readFile,
}

libs.push({
    action: Actions.add,
    from: Types.numbers,
    get: Types.number,
    fn: (...n: number[]): number => n.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0),
})

libs.push({
    action: Actions.subtract,
    from: Types.numbers,
    get: Types.number,
    fn: (...n: number[]): number => n.reduce((a, b) => a - b, 0),
})

libs.push({
    action: Actions.readFile,
    from: Types.string,
    get: Types.string,
    fn: async (s:string): Promise<string> => promisify(fs.readFile)(s, 'UTF8'),
})

libs.push({
    action: Actions.readFile,
    from: Types.string,
    get: Types.buffer,
    fn: async (s:string): Promise<Buffer> => promisify(fs.readFile)(s),
})

const library = (a: Actions, from: Types, get: Types, lib) => {
    const found = lodash.find(lib, fn => {
        return (
        lodash.isEqual(fn.from, from) &&
        lodash.isEqual(fn.get, get)
        );
    });
    if (!found) throw new Error('no conversion');
    return found.fn;
}

const { readFile } = Actions;
const { string: s } = Types;

const x = library(readFile, s, s, libs)

x('./tres.ts').then(console.log)
```

How can I retain typing information of `x`?

Comment: Is is a requirement that  `libs` is defined separately from where the values are added to it ? We can infer a very specific type for `libs` and have the `library` function return be fully typed. The problem is that the type of `libs` would have to be a good representation of what values it contains. The only way to do that if is `libs` is assigned all in one go when we init it.

Comment: I understand this constraint, no, It is not a requirement that `libs` is defined separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to preserve in `libs` the type  of the actual items in the array. The easiest way to do this is with a help of an extra function that will infer the type for `libs` based on the actual items in the array (including literal types for where `Actions` and `Types` are used).

With this information we can type the `library` function to extract the type of the function from `libs` that has the same `action`, `get` and `from` as the passed in types:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { promisify } from 'util';
import * as lodash from 'lodash';


export enum Types {
    number,
    numbers,
    string,
    buffer,
}

export enum Actions {
    add,
    subtract,
    readFile,
}

function makeLib<T extends Array<{action : A, from: F, get: G, fn: (...a: any[])=> any}>, A extends Actions, F extends Types, G extends Types>(...a:T){
    return a;
}
const libs = makeLib({
    action: Actions.add,
    from: Types.numbers,
    get: Types.number,
    fn: (...n: number[]): number => n.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0),
}, {
    action: Actions.subtract,
    from: Types.numbers,
    get: Types.number,
    fn: (...n: number[]): number => n.reduce((a, b) => a - b, 0),
}, {
    action: Actions.readFile,
    from: Types.string,
    get: Types.string,
    fn: async (s:string): Promise<string> => promisify(fs.readFile)(s, 'UTF8'),
}, {
    action: Actions.readFile,
    from: Types.string,
    get: Types.buffer,
    fn: async (s:string): Promise<Buffer> => promisify(fs.readFile)(s),
})

const library = <T extends Array<{action : Actions, from: Types, get: Types, fn: (...a: any[])=> any}>, A extends Actions, F extends Types, G extends Types>(a: A, from: F, get: G, lib: T) => {
    const found = lodash.find(lib, fn => {
        return (
        lodash.isEqual(fn.from, from) &&
        lodash.isEqual(fn.get, get)
        );
    });
    if (!found) throw new Error('no conversion');
    return found.fn as Extract<T[number], {action : A, from: F, get: G }>['fn'];
}

const { readFile } = Actions;
const { string: s } = Types;

const x = library(readFile, s, s, libs) // x is (s: string) => Promise<string

x('./tres.ts').then(console.log)

const x2 = library(Actions.subtract, Types.string, Types.string, libs)  // never
const x3 = library(Actions.subtract, Types.numbers, Types.number, libs)  //  (...n: number[]) => number
```

You can also use `strings` instead of enums:

```
function makeLib<T extends Array<{action : V, from: V, get: V, fn: (...a: any[])=> any}>, V extends string>(...a:T){
    return a;
}
const libs = makeLib({
    action: "add",
    from: "numbers",
    get: "number",
    fn: (...n: number[]): number => n.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0),
}, {
    action: "subtract",
    from: "numbers",
    get: "number",
    fn: (...n: number[]): number | null => n.reduce((a, b) => a - b, 0),
}, {
    action: "readFile",
    from: "string",
    get: "string",
    fn: async (s:string): Promise<string> => promisify(fs.readFile)(s, 'UTF8'),
}, {
    action: "readFile",
    from: "string",
    get: "buffer",
    fn: async (s:string): Promise<Buffer> => promisify(fs.readFile)(s),
})

const library = <T extends Array<{action : string, from: string, get: string, fn: (...a: any[])=> any}>, 
    A extends T[number]['action'], F extends T[number]['from'], G extends T[number]['get']>(a: A, from: F, get: G, lib: T) => {
    const found = lodash.find(lib, fn => {
        return (
        lodash.isEqual(fn.from, from) &&
        lodash.isEqual(fn.get, get)
        );
    });
    if (!found) throw new Error('no conversion');
    return found.fn as Extract<T[number], {action : A, from: F, get: G }>['fn'];
}

const { readFile } = Actions;
const { string: s } = Types;

const x = library("readFile", "string", "string", libs) // x is (s: string) => Promise<string

x('./tres.ts').then(console.log)

const x2 = library("subtract", "string", "string", libs)  // never
const x3 = library("subtract", "numbers", "number", libs)  //  (...n: number[]) => number
```

Comment: Again, amazing! I've been messing around with this, any idea why if you swap `subtract`'s  return type for a union say `number | null` and hover over `x3` it doesn't mention the null?

Comment: @ThomasReggi are you sure you have strictNullChecks turned on ? I an seeing `number | null`. If you don't have `strictNullChecks` number eats up `null`.

Comment: Could this work if `G` / `get` was just a string? Or does it have to be an enum value? I'm experimenting with `union(Types.File, Types.Null)` / `many(Types.File)` and it's breaking the type changes.  I updated `G extends string` but it's not doing the trick. Also updated enum to use string values as well.

Comment: @ThomasReggi It should work well with unions of string literals as well. We can actually improve on it if you want to use strings to have the `get` `from` and `action` params be inferred from `libs` on the library function (no need to define them separately) I can add it to the answer if you want.

Comment: @ThomasReggi added a string version as well, hope it helps :)